# Kubernetes, cannot mount NFS share via DNS

Tags: kubernetes, rpc, nfs, persistent-volumes

I am trying to mount a NFS share (outside of k8s cluster) in my container via DNS lookup, my config is as below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: service-a
spec:
  containers:
  - name: service-a
    image: dockerregistry:5000/centOSservice-a
    command: ["/bin/bash"]
    args: ["/etc/init.d/jboss","start"]
    volumeMounts:
      - name: service-a-vol
        mountPath: /myservice/por/data
  volumes:
    - name: service-a-vol
      nfs:
        server: nfs.service.domain
        path: "/myservice/data"
  restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

nslookup of `nfs.service.domin` works fine from my container. This is achiveded via `StubDomain` . However when creating the container it fails to resolve the nfs server. Error:

```
Warning  FailedMount  <invalid>  kubelet, worker-node-1  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "service-a-vol" : mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/44aabfb8-2767-11e8-bcf9-fa163ece9426/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/service-a-vol --scope -- mount -t nfs nfs.service.domain:/myservice/data /var/lib/kubelet/pods/44aabfb8-2767-11e8-bcf9-fa163ece9426/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/service-a-vol
Output: Running scope as unit run-27293.scope.
mount.nfs: Failed to resolve server nfs.service.domain: Name or service not known
mount.nfs: Operation already in progress
```

If i modify `server: nfs.service.domain` to `server: 10.10.1.11` this works fine! So to summarise

1. DNS resolution of the service works fine
2. Mounting via DNS resolution does not
3. Mounting via specific IP address works
4. I have tried `Headless Service` instead of StubDomain but the same issue exists

Any help much appreciated

*Update 1*: If i add an entry in the /etc/hosts files of worker/master nodes `10.10.1.11 nfs.service.domain` then my configuration above `server: nfs.service.domain` works. This is obviously not a desired workaround...

Comment: I had the same issue in the past. The problem was that K8s's team they doesn't implemented this part [take a look at this discussion](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44528). I don't know if they publish this feature so far.

Comment: thanks for the links @GiorgioCerruti, I managed to get it working if i modify the /etc/hosts of the nodes (i edited above), i didn't realise the NODE needed to resolve the service name in order to mount a vol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @Giorgio Cerruti and as referenced in [this github ticket](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44528/) among others this is currently not possible as the node needs to be able to resolve the DNS entry and it does not resolve kube-dns. Two possible solutions are:

1. Update `/etc/hosts` of each kubernetes node to resolve the NFS endpoint (as per update above). This is a primitive solution.
2. A more robust fix that would work for this NFS service and any other remote service in the same domain (as NFS) is to add the remote DNS server to the kubernetes nodes `resolv.conf`

   `someolddomain.org service.domain xx.xxx.xx
   nameserver 10.10.0.12
   nameserver 192.168.20.22
   nameserver 8.8.4.4`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the **full service name** and it's working fine for me. Like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: alpine
  labels:
    app: alpine
spec:
  containers:
    - name: alpine
      image: "alpine:latest"
      imagePullPolicy: "Always"
      command: [ "tail", "-f", "/dev/null" ]
      resources:
        limits:
          cpu: 100m
          memory: 100Mi
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /nfs
          name: nfs-vol
  volumes:
    - name: nfs-vol
      nfs:
        path: /exports
        server: nfs-server-svc.nfs-test.svc.cluster.local
```

Before that I was trying to use only the "simple" service name and it wasn't working.

I'm working on GKE, with the version "v1.20.10-gke.1600".

You can see more details [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44528#issuecomment-373017042).

Thanks.

Comment: linked solution only applies to GKE it seems (from reading the github issue)

Answer (score 0):

Facing similar issue. Trying to implement `busybox` init container or as side car which resolves hostname. I will update this post once I have implementation ready for init container.

Workaround that is working for me:

1. Use the services IP instead of the FQDN
2. Manually update the nodes hosts file (/etc/hosts) to make using the FQDN work

busybox example:

```
kubectl create -f https://k8s.io/examples/admin/dns/busybox.yaml
kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup nfs-service-tcp.default.svc.cluster.local
```

Answer (score -1):

try to use without " cluster.local "  and use only the name of nfs service name.

Answer (score -1):

try to use full service name as follow "[service-name].[service-namespace].svc.cluster.local".