# How to mount a nfs server running inside a kubernetes cluster by service name?

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, nfs

So we are running a kubernetes cluster on digital ocean.

Because volumes can only be mounted to one node at a time, we need to have a nfs server running, so multiple pods accross multiple nodes can access the same volume.

I pretty much followed [this](https://medium.com/swlh/quick-fix-sharing-persistent-disks-on-multiple-nodes-in-kubernetes-ef5541fd8376) guide to set this up.

The issue is, as soon as a pod tries to access the nfs server this error occurres:

```
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/64129b37-5463-4178-87ac-b35d62dd8c52/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/my-nfs --scope -- mount -t nfs nfs-server:/ /var/lib/kubelet/pods/64129b37-5463-4178-87ac-b35d62dd8c52/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/my-nfs
Output: Running scope as unit: run-r8962347bca094a909ba6324ddbabfe7f.scope
mount.nfs: Failed to resolve server nfs-server: Name or service not known
```

I also tried the fqdn but this didn't wor either.

---

What worked was setting a static ip for the nfs-server service and then mount this static ip. Sadly this isn't a option for us because we would have multiple of this nfs-servers running in different namespaces and assigning a static ip to each of the does not seam like an option.

---

It seams that there are a few people out there having the same issue:

- [Kubernetes, cannot mount NFS share via DNS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49274655/kubernetes-cannot-mount-nfs-share-via-dns)
- https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44528/#issuecomment-373017042
- https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/3688
- ...

---

I feel like there has to be smth. which can be done about this, the issue seams to exist since a few years and i can't imagin that no one is having the same troubles regarding this?

Also as said before having a static ip for the service or even tempering with the nodes dns entries does not feel like an option.

Any recomendations how to solve this, maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Is your cluster manged by digital ocean or is it your own?

Comment: It is managed by digital ocean.